# Max number of web methods?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service in asp.net 2.0 that has 234 methods. It seems that when I add another method the site does not compile in VS2005 until I remove one first. I get a message saying that the new method I just added does not exist in a file that belongs in the Microsoft.Net/.../Temporary Files directory. I have restarted IIS, closed down VS2005, removed all files from this temp directory but to no avail. The only way to get the code to compile is to remove another one so as to keep 234 methods....

I can consistency replicate this behaviour so it cannot be my code. 
Now I know this seems strange but it is true! One other strange thing is that exactly 100 of the method names begin with the word GetXXXyyyZZZ

Has anyone else experienced problems with the maximum number of methods that are allowed in a web service?
Many Thanks

Comment: I think this web service is an excellent candidate for http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: How can you guys make such judgements when you have not asked why this is the case? Again you ask a question that gets shot down in flames....

Answer (score 5):

I recommend organising your methods into related groups and splitting your single webservice into many smaller webservices according to those groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an answer just create a new webservice and create 235 web methods in it. If you have the same issue => there is a limit.

Answer (score 1):

you wont find a good solution for a bad design. its better to redesign web service so that consumers of the web service would see them in a group hierarchy and wont report this to thedailywtf :)

Comment: You are correct but my question still stands

"Has anyone else experienced problems with the maximum number of methods that are allowed in a web service?"